# Why the following code of multithreading is not working? The answer should be 20000 I believe

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Why am I not getting 20000 when the increment method is synchronized. I did the same thing with runnable and it worked.

```
   public class ThreadClass extends Thread
    {
            static int count=0;
            public synchronized void increment()
            {
                count++;
            }

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
            increment();
        }
    }; 

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadClass t1=new ThreadClass();
        ThreadClass t2= new ThreadClass();

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t2.join();
            t1.join();
            } 
        catch (Exception e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println(ThreadClass.count);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The JLS, for `synchronized` methods, [clearly states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6) the following:

> For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object for which the method was invoked) is used.

As a result, the two `ThreadClass` instances will lock independently, and there will be no common lock protecting bad writes to `count`.

Synchronize explicitly on `Threadclass.class` or make `increment()` static to actually synchronize in a manner that makes writes safe.